# how to pass two javascript variable in session at a time

Tags: javascript

setting java script variable in session.

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ABC",
  data: {title:title} ,
  success: function(data) {
      alert('success'+data);  
  }
 });
```

its working properly but i am trying to pass two javascript variable at a time.while

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ABC",
  data: {title:title} ,
  data:{message:message},
  success: function(data,data1) {
      alert('success'+data,+data1);  
  }
});
```

Is it possible to pass like above?
but it only passes one value,another value is null.how to pass two values at a time?

Answer (score 2):

```
data: {
         title:title, 
         message:message
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

To send to the server you just comma separate the values within the data object.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ABC",
  data: {
     title:title, 
     message:message
  },
  success: function(data) {
      alert('success'+data.title + data.message);  
  }
});
```

A similar approach on teh server will allow you to reference the values that get passed back.

This assumes the response is a json object looking like:

```
data {
    title: "Some Title",
    message: "Some message"
}
```

Comment: @user2598718 Feel free to pick an answer as correct - the site thrives on the questions getting answers ;)

Comment: having two functions with same url one returns null value
function t()
{
$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"BillServlet",
data1:{message1:ss},                                                                 
success:function(data1){
alert('success'+data1.message1)
 }});} //this function value getting null
function test()
{
$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"BillServlet",
data:{message:total},                                                                 
success:function(data){
alert('success'+data.message)
}});}
why this happen?

Comment: You will want to post that as a new question.  It will be easier to read and get more exposure to users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ABC",
  data: {
    title: title,
    message: message
  },
  success: function(data) {
      alert('success ' + data);  
  }
});
```

Comment: is it possible on one url,we differently send data variables?means for same url we can write two functions in same program?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Only use multiple ajax call's which will be executed on different events.

Comment: but,in my program there are two functions,in both functions i am using ajax call with same url='ABC' passing different data,then one value goes null,why this is so??

Comment: var ss=35;
function t()
{$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"BillServlet",data1:{message1:ss},                                                       
success:function(data1){
alert('success'+data1.message1)
} });} //this function value getting null                        function test()
{$.ajax({type:"POST", url:"BillServlet", data:{message:total},                                                                 
success:function(data){alert('success'+data.message)
} }); }<input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="test();"/>
<input type="button" value="check" onclick="t();"/>

Comment: function test()
{
$.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"BillServlet",
          data:{message:total,message1:ss},                                                                 
          success:function(data){
          alert('success'+data.message,data.message1)
          }         
          });  
} it works why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass 2 separate **`data`** variables in `ajax`.

Try merging both

```
data : { title: title, message: message }
```

Change like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ABC",
  data : { title: title, message: message },
  success: function(data) {
      console.log('success'+data);  //object will not be shown in alert
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use javaScript Object :

```
var YourData = {
    data1 : value1,
    data2 : value2,
    ....
    ....
};
```